# How to get margin intersections and area of each labeled component?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have segmented a binary image using expectation maximization. After that, I used OpenCV to labeled connected components by using the below implementation:

```
image = image.astype( 'uint8' )
nb_components, output, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(image, connectivity=8)
sizes = stats[:, -1];
```

From here, how can I get each component area and number of intersections with the image margin?

Below is what I have until now.

[image: Example]

Comment: each pixel has now a number that represents the label, the area (in pixels) is just the amount of pixels with that label. Hint: use numpy operations to do it faster. Not sure what you mean with margin intersection....

Comment: _margin intersections_? If they intersect, they are of the same label...

Comment: I edited the question, I want to find the intersections with the image margin

Comment: Can you please upload an image highlighting what you want to find?

Comment: @Miki I added the image, I'm trying to remove that yellow part which are false positives as described in the paper http://www.scielo.edu.uy/pdf/cleiej/v19n1/v19n1a07.pdf

Comment: This _margin intersection_ thing makes no sense. Here a threshold should already work pretty well

Comment: @Miki, I will try that so